# Windows Phone 7 ScrollView?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a scrollView in phone7?

I have this code

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=0; i<23; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button() { 
            Content="newbutton "+i, 
            HorizontalAlignment =HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 20+(i*60), 0, 0), 
        };
        btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_click);

        ContentPanel.Children.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

to add 23 buttons to my screen, what is the way to scrolling down the page to show all of the 23 buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `ContentPanel` is a `StackPanel`.

In XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can use the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to scroll to the end of the page.

However, if you have other `UIElement`s above the `ScrollViewer` those will still occupy the top of your screen with only the section occupied by the `ScrollViewer` being scrolled. To prevent that you'll have to have all the `UIElement`s, including *ContentPanel*, be placed in the `ScrollViewer`.